# How to compile this Assembly code?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I found these codes on Wikipedia (italian) page about "Assembly" with some description lines:

*...Sample program "Hello world" in assembly Intel x86 with Intel syntax (uses calls to the operating system DOS). Is not compatible with versions Assembly UNIX GNU:*

```
   MODEL SMALL
    STACK 100H
    .DATA
        HW      DB      "hello, world", 13, 10, '$'
    .CODE
    .STARTUP
        MOV AX, @data
        MOV DS, AX
        MOV DX, OFFSET HW
        MOV AH, 09H
        INT 21H
        MOV AX, 4C00H
        INT 21H
    END
```

...

*...An example of code written in C-asm (using the Intel x86 assembly), which displays a number in binary data received as input, is as follows:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() 
{
    int a;

    /* Acquisizione del valore numerico */
    printf("Inserisci un valore compreso tra -32768 e 32768: "); 
    scanf("%d", &a); 

    /* Visualizzazione del messaggio di risposta */
    printf("Il valore corrispondente in binario è: "); 

    /* Keyword per delimitare le sezioni di codice Assembly */
    asm 
    { 
        /* Visualizzazione della stringa di bit corrispondente */
        MOV BX,WORD PTR a
        MOV CX,00Ah
    }

    /* Etichetta esterna */
    Ciclo: 
        asm
        {
            /* Estrazione di un bit */
            MOV DL,00H
            RCL BX,1   /* Il valore del bit viene posto nel flag di carry */
            ADC DL,'0' /* Determino il carattere da visualizzare */
            MOV AH,02H /* Visualizzazione */
            INT 21h
            Loop Ciclo
        } 
    return 0;
}
```

Which is the compiler or the command for compile these codes? I tried with gcc but I have to modify the syntax.

Comment: You don't compile assembly code, you assemble it with an assembler. Do you have a DOS env?

Comment: @Marco Favorito As the assembler code is a MASM compatible assembler code then it seems you should use some old MS C++.

Comment: This is very old 16 bit MS-DOS code for an antique C compiler.  I'm not sure which one, maybe Turbo-C?  Unless you are already proficient in C and have s strong inclination for archaeology, you are wasting your time.

Comment: @Vlad: this code probably pre-dates MS-C++

Comment: Isn't the first asm code for generating the obsolete .com executable format?

Comment: @Weather Vane  No, it is not a com module. The module has Small memory model. For com module you have to specify org 100h

Comment: To produce a .COM program, the directive is .model tiny.

Comment: This indeed looks like the extremely old Turbo C I started with, including its inline assembler syntax. Wasn't `<conio.h>` one of Borland's own unique peculiarities? I must admit `<iostream.h>` seems to refute that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both fragments are MS-DOS assembly.

The first fragment can be built with FASM. FASM can target MS-DOS.

For the second one, you'll need a *very* old Microsoft C compiler, something like Quick C 2.x or MSC 6.x. The latest version of Microsoft C that was capable of emitting 16-bit code shipped with Visual C++ 1.54 IIRC. All of those compilers have been long discontinued.

To execute either of those, you'd need a MS-DOS machine, or an emulator such as DOSBox. The Windows command line won't do.

Comment: VIsual C / C++ 4.1 cd-rom includes 16 bit Visual C / C++ 1.52, but not the assembler.

Comment: It'll do for the second fragment. Inline assembly was supported in 1.52.

Comment: 1) Both cases are written in Intel x86 syntax, aren't? Which are the newer versions of those languages? 
2) My purpose is to make working the "int 21h" in other contexts and in more frequently used Assembly language: I need necessarly a MS-DOS emulator or MS-DOS machine? Following Windows OS's versions are right for this? 
3) What are the steps to obtain a executable from a C source code to Assembly code, so allowing me to modify the code with "int 21h", and finally to produce an executable (possibly working)? (i.e. "gcc prog.c -S ;gcc -o prog prog.s"). I can't use a UNIX GNU standard, isn't?

Comment: Int21h is a purely MS-DOS feature. It won't work neither on modern Windows nor on Linux/Unix. 1) Yes. Both C and assembly are still around, but the techniques for interacting with the operating system are different. 2) You need a MS-DOS emulator or machine. 3) You need a compiler/assembler, see my answer.

Comment: The dos console window in 32 bit versions of Windows also supports 16 real mode MSDOS programs somewhat similar to a virtual machine. It includes debug.com, a 16 bit real mode debugger. If you're running a 64 bit version of windows, you can create a Virtual PC and "install" MSDOS to it (transferring files is a bit messy). You could also use DOSBOX.